# Menu With toolbarTray problem in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

when i add a toolBarTray at the bottom of my menu, the menu goes behind the toolBarTray !

what is the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[codeproject.com/KB/menus/WPFMergeMenu.aspx](http://codeproject.com/KB/menus/WPFMergeMenu.aspx)